# Setting element ID in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, qtp

I am trying to add ID to GWT element. I have tried following code.

In SubscribeView.java file, existingFundRadioButton field is defined, I am setting an ID for it as follows:

```
DOM.setElementAttribute( existingFundRadioButton.getElement(), 
                         "ID",
                         "existingFundRadioButton" )
```

I tried using `existingFundRadioButton.getElement().setId("existingFundRadioButton")` but it's not working.

This is my code.

```
<g:FlowPanel width="100%">
    <g:FlowPanel>

        <g:HTMLPanel ui:field='searchPanel' styleName="{res.fdcWidgets.box}">
            <table class="{res.fdcWidgets.inputTable}">
                <colgroup>
                    <col width="25%" />
                    <col width="75%" />
                </colgroup>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <fdc:I18NRadioButton name="fund"
                                ui:field="existingFundRadioButton" checked="true"
                                messageKey="buy.existingFundLabel" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <hli:HoldingsListBoxWidget ui:field="holdingsListBox" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>

        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:FlowPanel>
    <g:FlowPanel styleName="{res.fdcWidgets.contentRightColumn}">
        <fund:FundInformationWidget ui:field="fundInformationWidget" />
    </g:FlowPanel>
</g:FlowPanel>
```

Comment: It is a nice practice to close the question if it gets solved either by choosing an answer or by posting your own answer. Stackoverflow would not be this much helpful if the questions did not get closed!!!

Answer (score 2):

### Old Solution

If you are stuck on a old version of GWT - For RadioButton we use a browser specific approach. We this by extending RadioButton.

```
MyRadioButton extends RadioButton{
        public void setId( String id )
        {
            getElement().setId( id );
            Element child = DOM.getChild( getElement(), 0 );
            DOM.setElementAttribute( child, "id", id + CONST_INPUT_ELEMENT );
            final Element e_label = DOM.getChild( getElement(), 1 );
            // Handling IE
            DOM.setElementAttribute( e_label, "htmlFor", id + CONST_LABEL_ELEMENT );
            // Handling Other Browsers
            DOM.setElementAttribute( e_label, "for", id + CONST_LABEL_ELEMENT );
        }
}
```

### New Solution

For those lucky enough to have latest GWT that supports ensureDebugId across all widgets you can use `ensureDebugId("someid")` available in all ui elements inherited from UIObject!!!!

Comment: Thank you for reply. I tried using elementname.ensureDebugId("abc") and it worked.

Comment: Thanks to YOU!!! We never updated to this approach as the earlier one was working! Its time to update our wrappers :) . Of course the above answer might be needed in some older versions of GWT.

Comment: You can add ensureDebugId("abc") method in java code or You can set debugId attribute in ui.xml file...It worked for me